# Including bias die properties in probability calculations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose I have a die with sides $1,2,3,4,5,5$. What is the probability of getting any order of $1,2,3,4,5$ in $5$ rolls?

Would I be right in saying you can't use combinations to try and calculate this because the probability of each outcome isn't equally likely?

Comment: Imagine your die has sides 1,2,3,4,5,6, as usual and compute the probability that the 5 first rolls are 1,2,3,4,5 in any order or 1,2,3,4,6 in any order. To compute the probability that the 5 first rolls are 1,2,3,4,5 in any order, compute the probability that the 5 first rolls are different and use symmetry. The final result might be $$2\cdot\frac16\cdot\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2}{6\cdot6\cdot6\cdot6\cdot6}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try thinking like this:

- What is the probability of rolling 1,2,3,4,5 in *exactly that order*?
- What about rolling them in some other order, say 2,1,3,4,5. Is the probability still the same?
- How many different orderings are there?
- The probability of rolling any of the orderings is the sum of the probabilities for any particular ordering.

Comment: there's 5! orderings. the probability of rolling 1,2,3,4,5 say, would be (1/6)*(1/6)*(1/6)*(1/6)*(2/6). The probability for all permutations are the same?

Comment: so 5!*(1/6)*(1/6)*(1/6)*(1/6)*(2/6)?

Comment: @Qwertford: Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:**

For verification, here is a simulation of a million 5-roll experiments,
which should approximate the probability in the original question
correct to two or three decimal places. The vector `pr` governs the
probabilities of faces labeled 1 through 5. On the $i$th roll,
`x[i]` is the number of unique values observed.

```
pr = c(1,1,1,1,2)/6
m = 10^6;  x = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
  faces = sample(1:5, 5, rep=T, prob=pr)
  x[i] = length(unique(faces)) }
mean(x==5)
## 0.030952        # aprx prob of all 5 values    
2*factorial(5)/6^5
## 0.0308642       # exact prob
```